# Trigger a Stored Procedure on Insert or Update Triggers

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, db2

I have two Triggers for a table that share identical functionality. A record is inserted into or updated in said table, and some of its fields are Inserted into another table, or elsewhere into the same table. If it is a new record, the Insert Trigger triggers. If it is an already-existing record, the Update Trigger triggers.

It isn't rocket science.

However, I'm entertaining the idea of simplifying these Triggers by having each of them call a Stored Procedure that will replicate the above functionality. I'm going this route because a separate table I'm working with doesn't allow an After Insert Trigger to be used in this manner with the code it contains, and I'd like to find a workaround. I'm not sure if it'll work or not, but I'd like to give it a shot.

I have no idea how to go about it, though. I utilize variables that are populated with data from tables Joined to the triggering one, and `N.field` or `O.field` throughout the Triggers. Is this possible if the Trigger calls a Proc? If it's called For Each Row, are the New and Old fields available to be used within the Proc? If so, how? Input and Output parameters with regard to Stored Procedures are new to me. I don't even know if what I'm asking makes as much sense written out as it does in my head.

For example, we'll say I'm working with a table called Cars.

```
ID  |VIN    |CATEGORY
----------------------------------------------
1    A1234   A
2    A1235   A
3    B1234   B
```

If a record is Inserted into Cars, the first character of `CARS.VIN` should be Inserted into `CARS.CATEGORY`. If a record is Updated, `CARS.CATEGORY` should be, as well, referencing `N.VIN`. I have a Trigger for each of these and they work fine.

The minutiae of the 'why' aside, is it possible to contain the functionality of these Triggers into a Proc that either can call? How would I go about the initial steps of creation for said Proc?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a generated (computed) column?

Comment: You'd have to enlighten me as to just what that is, I'm afraid.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020109.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a trigger, consider defining `CATEGORY` as a [generated column](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020109.html), for example

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
   id       INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   vin      VARCHAR(17),
   category CHAR(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LEFT( vin, 1 ) )
)
```